# file_get_contents and invalid character

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get json response from stackoverflow api with file_get_contents(), but comes back to me  strange chars like `I–%&/mÊ{JõJ×àt¡€`$Ø@ìÁˆÍæ’ìiG#)«*ÊeVe]f@ etc etc...

Ok, the address is  http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/779187/

My code is

`$json_res = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/779187/"))`
obvious the response of json_dec is NULL because the string is not json.
I also tried directly dump value without json_decode, the result is "I–%&/mÊ{JõJ×àt¡€`$..."

thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gzdecode` to decode compressed content. You should use implementation from [this page](http://digitalpbk.com/php/file_get_contents-garbled-gzip-encoding-website-scraping) if you don't have gzdecode function. I have checked that it works with the page you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 2):

The API Response is GZIP'd. Refer to this page to decoding responses: http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/gzip

If you switch to cURL, then you can use the CURLOPT_ENCODING option to decode it.

```
$url = 'http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/779187/';
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
curl_close($ch); 
if($status=='200') {
    $data = json_decode($output);
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($data,true) . '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Thank Jamie, it is elegant solution, but cURL is not active on the hostig (is a bore) where i want implement this function.
Sure, i'll use it where the cURL is active.

Answer (score 0):

Decompress it with [`gzinflate`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.gzinflate.php) first.